# Why this string is not converting to Integer?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char, reverse

I'm trying to convert the string `r` to an int(`num`). But it keeps returning 0. Note: When I was returning the string, the answer(reversed number) was correct. My code looks like this:

```
string n, r = "";
        cin >> n;

        for (int i = n.length(); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            r += n[i];
        }

        int num;

        istringstream(r) >> num;

        cout << num << endl;
```

Comment: try std::stoi its there to convert strings to integers. If input is not ok it will throw an exception telling you what's wrong : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: I did this, I don't even return a value.

Comment: try std::reverse, you shouldn't start at n.length(), but at n.length()-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the character `n[n.length()]` is equal to `'\0'`

That is when the index of the subscript operator is equal to the size of the string then it *"returns a reference to an object of type
charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior."* (The C++ Standard)

So your reversed string starts with the terminating zero.

Rewrite your for loop the following way

```
    for ( auto i = n.length(); i != 0;  )
    {
        r += n[--i];
    }
```

or

```
    for ( auto i = n.length(); i != 0; --i )
    {
        r += n[i - 1];
    }
```

Of course instead of the for loop you could just write

```
r.assign( n.rbegin(), n.rend() );
```

Pay attention to that the initialization of the variable `r` with an empty string

```
string n, r = "";
```

is redundant. You could just write

```
string n, r;
```

Comment: Yeah, it works!

Comment: btw, ```The value of the character n[n.length()] is equal to '\0'``` can you clarify this? I didn't understand :(

Comment: @AhnaafAlRafee It is according to the C++ Standard starting from C++ 11. From the description of the subscript operator "Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior."